# How is session initialized in Django?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I'm still confused about what happens after we enable session on Django. The documentation says each `Request` will have a session dictionary associated with it. Does that mean a default session will be initialized with the only key being the session ID? And if sessions are unique per browser, do all the `request` have access to the same session when a user logs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session id will be the only data associated with the session when initialized. And if I understand your second question, you can access sessions through the request object from any view where you can access a request object once the user is logged in. If there is a request object and the user is logged in you can access the session and can be accessed like any other dictionary. Here is a [explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions) of Django sessions by mozzila.

Comment: Each logged in user will have an unique session id that's permanent right? Is that the same for anonymous users on a browser basis?

Comment: Sessions are not permanent, they expire. This can be set using `session.set_expiry()`. Yes it works the same way for anonymous users. It just looks for a cookie stored in the browser storage

Comment: that means if the user cleans their browser cookies, they get a new session the next time they visit the site?

Comment: Technically yes.